# How to customize cURL options in API Platform?

Tags: php, symfony, web-services, curl, api-platform.com

Im working with Symfony 6 using Api Platform, Im trying to call a webservice using custom cURL options, but I feel a bit lost, I am not sure where or how I have to specify that options. the cURL that I have been given to make the call is the following.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://wsd.server-test-enviroment.es/v1/sms/sendSMS' \
--header 'x-api-key: c3f4f6bc-f12a-433b-9026-ebbf6cc7933c' \
--form 'destinatarios="666777888"' \
--form 'mensaje="Test"'
-k
```

When I call the service using a POST method like in this image, the cURL should be replaced like in the example

[image: ApiPlatform_test]

Im still a newbie and is my first project so I am not used working with cURL or symfony. I have tried using a controller to do the call and send the parameters but I think im making a lot of mistakes. This is the controller:

```
class SMSController extends AbstractController
    {
        public function __invoke(Request $request): JsonResponse
        {   
            $sms = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
            $client = HttpClient::create();

            $data = [
                'destinatarios' => $sms['destinatarios'],
                'mensaje' => $sms['mensaje']
            ];

             //opciones del cURL
                $options = [
                    'headers' => [
                        'x-api-key' => 'c3f4f6bc-f12a-433b-9026-ebbf6cc7933c',
                    ],
                    'body' => $data,
                    'verify_peer' => false //  ignorar la verificación SSL
                ];

            // Realiza la solicitud HTTP
            $respuesta = $client->request('POST', 'https://wsd.server-test-enviroment.es/v1/sms/sendSMS', $options);

            // Obtiene el contenido de la respuesta
            $content = $respuesta->getContent();


            return new JsonResponse($content);
        }
    }
```

I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me, what I'm doing wrong or how I should do it.

Comment: It looks like the controller perform the request you intended to do. What is not working?

Comment: @A.L Although API platform does not directly execute that curl, the controller it calls 
should execute it. I am receiving a 403 code (forbidden returned), maybe I am not sending the x-api-key correctly, I don't know what it could be.

Comment: This is not a direct solution but you may try [EightPointsGuzzleBundle](https://github.com/8p/EightPointsGuzzleBundle), it eases the configuration of the headers, etc. And it provides debug tools in a `dev` environment: requests are shown in the profiler.